# How to do correct redirection with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Login .jsp page sends post form auth data to AuthenticationController:

```
@PostMapping("/authentication")
public String auth(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @Valid @ModelAttribute("loginUser") LoginUser loginUser) throws ServletException {
   request.login(loginUser.getLogin(), loginUser.getPassword());
   SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
   if (savedRequest != null) {
       if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN") || request.isUserInRole("ROLE_MODERATOR")) {
           return "redirect:/admin";
       } else {
            return "redirect:/";
       }
   } else {
       return "redirect:/";
   }
}
```

HomeController code:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String homePage(Model model) {
    List<Product> topList = productService.getTop();
    if (!topList.isEmpty()) {
        deleteBrandName(topList);
    }
    model.addAttribute("topList", topList);
    return "web/index";
}
```

HttpConfigure code :

```
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
.loginProcessingUrl("/login/auth")
.defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
.failureUrl("/login?error")
.usernameParameter("login")
.passwordParameter("password")
.and()
...
.csrf().disable()
```

After success login I have this:
[image]

AOP log is:

```
2021-02-11 22:32:16 INFO : -------------------- Login -----------------------
2021-02-11 22:32:16 INFO : USER "test" entered.
2021-02-11 22:32:16 INFO : --------------------------------------------------
```

But I always have **a login page**.

How can I do correct redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

In the form tag, add the following parameter.

```
redirect="true"
```

Everything works fine now.